# What does these mean in angularjs ui-router : ' ', '/' while setting up routes like below

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, custom-routes

I have routes setup as shown below. could someone please help understand what does '' & '/' mean when it comes to routing..

Route configuration below;

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('', function ($state) {
    $state.go('login');
});

$urlRouterProvider.when('/', function ($state) {
    $state.go('login');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It tells how `ui-view` should change when your $location/url is changed (user clicked `<a href="/login">`). Your template must contain at least one element that has `ui-view` attribute. Using `$state.go('login')` will active the login state, which changes your ui-view etc. For more information, check [URL-Routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

Answer (score 0):

Those are the hashed part of the url, it is for routing, say if you type the url http://localhost/#/ or http://localhost/# it has to go to login page, that is what you are doing there, it will go the state associated with the mapped url.